# ace tooltip global to show dynamic data

Tags: jsf, datatable, icefaces

I am using ace tootip to show data on data table.

```
<ace:tooltip id="tooltip" global="true" />
<ace:datatable>
<ace:column id="id" headertext="header">
<h:outputText id="id" title="tooltip data"  value="#{}" />
</ace:column>
</ace:datatable>
```

Above code show title attribute data in data table.

Below code data for datatable dynamic data.

```
<ace:delegate id="tablevar">
<ace:datatable value=#{bean.list} var="var1">
<ace:column id="id" headertext="header">
<h:outputText id="tool" title="tooltip data"  value="#{var1.values}" />
</ace:column>
</ace:datatable>
</ace:delegate>

<ace:tooltip id="tooltip" fordelegate="tablevar" for="tool" fetch="#{var1}" store=#{bean.data} />
```

But delegate is taking time to load data. acetooltip global(first mentoned code) is fast but it wont show dynamic data. can we use acetooltip global to show dynamic data based on row without lading.

Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ace tooltip global will also work for dynamic data and data table.

we just need to add data title="#{var1.values}" in title attribute. one other thing is we need to add title attribute h:outputlabel tag instead of h:panelgroup for global to work.

I recommend using ace:tooltip global rather than Delegate version of ace:tooltip.
I dont see any benefit in delegate and it is slow.

Thanks.